# touch.identifier value is always 0 for different touch points

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was testing out the example for multi touch in canvas from Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Touch_events

Here's the issue I am facing: the identifier attribute for Touch interface ALWAYS shows integer value of 0 on every single touch point on laptop (I am using Google Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m), which is a touch ultrabook.

According to the specs, identifier should be unique for each touch but it shows up as 0 for every new touch point on the canvas.

Please help me understand what's causing it because I want to use the identifier unique value to map it to different colors and make a paint on touch canvas like application.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment, I take it you're referring to this bit of code in particular:

```
 function ongoingTouchIndexById(idToFind) {
      for (var i=0; i<ongoingTouches.length; i++) {
          var id = ongoingTouches[i].identifier;
          if (id == idToFind) {
            return i;
          }
        }
    return -1;    // not found
}
```

As you can see, this function *either* returns the *index* of a given id (if a particular `Touch` hasn't ended yet, since the handler was last called), or returns -1.
The code page you linked to is pretty straight forward, IMO: Each time a new touchstart event is registered, the id's of on-going (or past) touch events are checked and the corresponding ids are removed from a global (evil) array. There's a ton of reasons why this is done, but I'll leave those for you to find (or ask a follow-up question about, once you've tried to familiarize yourself with the code).

The identifier is unique for each distinct changedtouch. Now, you didn't provide the code you're using, but my guess would be that you're not getting the unique identifier from the right place:

```
var ids = [];
for (var i=0;i<e.changedTouches.length;i++)
{
    ids.push(e.changedTouches[0].identifier);
}
console.log(ids);
```

If you're touching with more than 1 digit, `ids` should contain a distinct id for each touch.
I might be barking up the wrong tree altogether here, but again: add your code to the question so we can be sure. But you could be reassigning the id over and over, only leaving you with the value for the last `Touch` in the `changedTouches` array.
You could also be trying to get the identifier directly from the `event` object. Or you could be doing something else, all the same.

Check your console, log the event object and check the `changedTouches` property of that event.

Comment: Hey, this is the example I am referring to. https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/touchevents.html (from link I stated above)

Comment: @RahulMathur: Updated my answer. AFAIK, the code used in the linked page isn't using the identifier, but the index of a given touch event. The first of which, will always be 0... also bear in mind that it's only an example page, not copy-pastable code

Comment: Ah gotcha, can't believe I missed that! So how do I get the unique identifier property?

Comment: Well, for index 0: `ongoingTouches[0].identifier` or `event.changedTouches[0].identifier`... as my initial sample shows

Comment: I still get 0 in console. Did you try the example out?

Comment: One more thing: why do I get touches[I].pageX (for eg) value for different touch point different and it works for all attributes except identifier attribute. I get a value for all attributes except identifier. I don't really comprehend this.

Comment: @RahulMathur: Log the `touches` object(s), and check to see if they really have an `identifier` property. Personally, I don't get your last comment, so perhaps expand on it a little more...